# Generate expiring activator token or a key hash in rails manually

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, token

I'm trying to verify a link that will expire in a week. I have an activator_token stored in the database, which will be used to generate the link in this format: http://www.example.com/activator_token. (And not activation tokens generated by Devise or Authlogic.)

Is there a way to make this activator token expire (in a week or so) without comparing with updated_at or some other date. Something like an encoded token, which will return nil when decoded after a week. Can any existing modules in Ruby do this? I don't want to store the generated date in the database or in an external store like Redis and compare it with Time.now. I want it to be very simple, and wanted to know if something like this already exists, before writing the logic again.

Comment: Why don't you want to store the generated date in the database? What I would do is use https://github.com/javan/whenever to run periodic rake tasks for removing expired stuff from the database, by checking the date on the objects. I'd use whenever because it plays well with capistrano

Comment: It's not that I don't want to store it. Want to know if there is any existing mechanism which will take care of expiry, like it will return nil if I try to decode an encoded token after it got expired. If there is nothing like that, I'll have to write some logic like you say.

Comment: Now I see! Long story short, you want to use https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for! You can add it as an answer, Damiano! :)

Comment: @DamianoStoffie , Is there any way to reduce the length of this JSON web token? I need to use it in the URL.

Comment: I don't think you can have links that are both short and cryptographically strong. I understand the UX issues that come from a long link, but as long as it doesn't exceed practical limits you should be fine. Otherwise you have to store stuff in the database. I don't know how to user ruby-jwt, I just gave you the link

Comment: @DamianoStoffie Do you have any example or maybe a blog reference to implement what you are telling?

Comment: I am updating my answer :)

Comment: @DamianoStoffie I have to apologize because I wasn't clear enough. I have worked with `JWT` in _NodeJS_ so it makes me sense what are you talking about! But what I really wanted to know or see as an example was how to implement _"to store the generated tokens in the database and use `whenever` gem to run periodic rake tasks for removing expired stuff from the database"_ . If it is possible, it may come in handy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is: https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt .
Here is some boilerplate code so you can try it out yourself.

```
require 'jwt'

# generate your keys when deploying your app.
# Doing so using a rake task might be a good idea
# How to persist and load the keys is up to you!
rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key

# do this when you are about to send the email
exp = Time.now.to_i + 4 * 3600
payload = {exp: exp, discount: '9.99', email: 'user@example.com'}
# when generating an invite email, this is the token you want to incorporate in
# your link as a parameter
token = JWT.encode payload, rsa_private, 'RS256'
puts token
puts token.length

# this goes into your controller
begin
    #token = params[:token]
    decoded_token = JWT.decode token, rsa_public, true, { :algorithm => 'RS256' }
    puts decoded_token.first
    # continue with your business logic
rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
    # Handle expired token
    # inform the user his invite link has expired!
    puts "Token expired"
end
```